# What determines the eastward speed that mid-latitude high pressure/low pressure systems move at?

Tags: weather

Do they move at the group velocity of Rossby Waves? Or do they move at the phase velocity of Rossby Waves? Or some other speed?

Comment: Are you talking about the Jetstream, which does influence the movement of high pressure/low pressure systems? Rossby waves play an important role in the modulation of the jetstream, but they move westward.